# Create a range from consecutive zip codes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a zone table with starting and ending zip codes, but it was loaded with each zip code individually. I now need to create a report that displays the zips in the assigned zones, but it is returning a bunch of records. What I want to do is create a range from this list of consecutive zips.

My table contains the following

```
FromZip ToZip
07543   07543
07604   07604
07509   07509
07510   07510
07511   07511
07512   07512
07513   07513
07514   07514
```

I would like to return

```
FromZip ToZip
07543   07543
07604   07604
07509   07514
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try a query like below

```
select 
  MIN(FromZip) as FromZip, 
  MAX(ToZip) as ToZip
from 
 (
  Select 
   *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ToZip asc) as ranking 
   from tbl
 ) t  
 group by 
   (CAST(ToZip AS INT)-Ranking)
 order by 
   (CAST(ToZip AS INT)-Ranking)
```

**[Live SQL demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7838f/1)**